# FSL 6.0.6 installation on ubuntu 20.04 takes too much time

Tags: software-installation, debian, python-2.7

**Why does FSL 6.0.6 installation on Ubuntu 20.04 take too much time?**
It started good but stuck at 54% for nearly 9 hours. Since there was no error , I waited and got a message after approx 9 hours that it's finally installed.

See the command and process below:

```
*(base) amit@d770:~/Softs$ python2.7 /home/amit/Downloads/fslinstaller.py           
FSL installer version: 2.1.1
Press CTRL+C at any time to cancel installation
Installation log file: /tmp/fslinstaller_QbpWgx.log
FSL 6.0.6 selected for installation
Where do you want to install FSL?
Press enter to install to the default location [/home/amit/fsl]
FSL installation directory [/home/amit/fsl]: /home/amit/Softs/fsl
Downloading FSL environment specification from https://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsldownloads/fslconda/releases/fsl-6.0.6_linux-64.yml...
Installing FSL in /home/amit/Softs/fsl
Downloading miniconda from https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/download/4.10.3-7/Miniforge3-4.10.3-7-Linux-x86_64.sh...
Installing miniconda at /home/amit/Softs/fsl...#####################] 64.4 / 64.4 MB |
Installing FSL into /home/amit/Softs/fsl...##############] 100 / 100 % -
[#################################################                                                                                                ] 44 / 100 % \                                                                                                                                                         4[###################################################################################                                                                                          ] 4[###################################################################################                                                                                          ] 4[###################################################################################                                                                                          ] 4[###################################################################################                                                                                          ] 4[###################################################################################                                                                                          ] 4[########################################################################################                                                                                     ] 51 / 100 % -[########################################################################################                                                                                     ] 51 / 10[########################################################################################                                                                                     ] 51 / 10[##############################################################################################                                                                               ] 54 / 100 % /
[##############################################################################################                                                                               ] 54 / 100 % \
[##############################################################################################                                                                               ] 54 / 100 % /
Adding FSL configuration to /home/amit/.profile#############################################################################################################################] 100 / 100 % \
Adding FSL configuration to /home/amit/Documents/MATLAB/startup.m

FSL successfully installed
Open a new terminal, or log out and log back in, for the environment changes to take effect.

(base) amit@d770:~/0Softs$*
```

**It's finally installed, but you you need to have patience.**